# Setting inline styles in React using strings and not CSSProperties

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript

Is there any way to set an inline style in React without using `CSSProperties`?

I'm importing a bunch of SVGs that have styles defined inline in the regular fashion, with things like

`style="fill:#bfd9ff;"`

To convert that to work in React, right now I'm changing it to:

`style={{fill: "#bfd9ff"}}`

The thing is.. this is kind of a pain to do, even with regex (since not everything is the same format). I really wish I could just keep the strings as-is and not have to manually change each style attribute to a `CSSProperties` object.

Is there an alternate attribute or something that I could use to make it easier?

I'm imagining something like `styleString="fill:#bfd9ff"` where setting that attribute would fill in the `style` tag of the generated DOM element with the provided string, because then I could just do a quick replace of `style` to `styleString`. But I've done a bit of searching and can't seem to find anything like this, is there no other way than to just manually set up all the styles?

Comment: You could write your own function to convert a string like this to the required object - but it wouldn't be particularly pleasant. I'm not sure why it's any more of a "pain" to type the correct form than the string form - unless of course you're doing a mass copy-paste exercise, perhaps from an existing CSS file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried importing your svgs as components? That way you could keep them in `.svg` files and you can keep the usual `style=...` syntax.

```
// importing a logo SVG and embedding it in JSX
import { ReactComponent as Logo } from './logo.svg';
const MyComponent = () => {
  return (
     ...
     <Logo />
  );
}
```

See: https://medium.com/@rossbulat/working-with-svgs-in-react-d09d1602a219